# How to put a string of json string representation into a json string: AWS eventbridge

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-event-bridge

I hope the title makes sense.
What I am trying to do is create the AWS cdk code to have an AWS eventbridge rule trigger a lambda function with static input. What the input needs to look like is this

```
"""{
  "resource": "/{proxy+}",
  "path": "/jobs/sendRepoJob",
  "httpMethod": "POST",
  "requestContext": "{}",
  "queryStringParameters": null,
  "multiValueQueryStringParameters": null,
  "pathParameters": null,
  "stageVariables": null,
  "body": "{\"Configs\":{\"_url\":\"<some_url>",\"name\":\"<some_name>\"},\"Configs2\":{\"_url\":\"<some_url>",\"name\":\"<some_name>\"}}"
  "isBase64Encoded": null
}"""
```

Basically, I need the json string as the body in the static input for the eventbridge rule. However, when I try to create the rule with AWS CDK, the `events.CfnRule.TargetProperty` object takes a json string as input as seen from the documentation https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v1/python/aws_cdk.aws_events/CfnRule.html#aws_cdk.aws_events.CfnRule.TargetProperty

My code for creating event in AWS CDK is shown below.

```
rule = events.CfnRule(self,
    "InvokeApiRule",
    description="test",
    schedule_expression="rate(2 minutes)",
    state="ENABLED",
    role_arn=role.role_arn,
    targets=[events.CfnRule.TargetProperty(
        arn="<lambda_arn>",
        id="<someID>",
        dead_letter_config=events.CfnRule.DeadLetterConfigProperty(
            arn="<dlq_arn>"
        ),
        input = tmp_input
)])
```

When I try making the json string, in the script for "tmp_input", it automatically converts it to json when creating the stack. I need it to be a string, and stay a string as I showed above.

Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: You use something like this when creating the dictionary: `"body": json.dumps(config)`

Comment: so the entire thing needs to be a string not a dictionary. Sorry I'll update that

Comment: You also have to use `json.dumps()` on the whole thing. You use nested calls to get the nested JSON.

Answer (score 0):

A python function `json.dumps()` converts a dictionary into a json. The result would add escape to the quotes, e.g.:

```
{
  "my_json" : "{
    \"resource\": \"/{proxy+}\",
    \"path\": \"/jobs/sendRepoJob\",
    \"httpMethod\": \"POST\"
    ...
  }"
}
```

Comment: works, but I'd like to avoid doing this manually as it is quite a big string.

Comment: `json.dumps()` is a perfect solution: it does exactly what I describe in my answer.

Comment: Yup worked great

Comment: If you update answer I can mark it correct